# When changing the sign of the modulus of a complex number why do I have to change the sign of the argument too?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have the set $ A = ${$\alpha(1+i) : a \in \mathbb{R}$}. And I have to compute $2iz^2=\alpha(1+i)$. This complex equation has the solutions $z = \pm \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2}}(\cos({-\frac{\pi}{8}}) + i\sin{({-\frac{\pi}{8}}))}$ for $ \alpha \ge 0  $ and $z = \sqrt{\frac{-\alpha}{2}} \sqrt{-(\cos({-\frac{\pi}{4}}) + i\sin{({-\frac{\pi}{4}}}))} = \sqrt{\frac{-\alpha}{2}}(\cos({-\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{\pi}{2}) + i\sin{({-\frac{\pi}{8}+ \frac{\pi}{2}}))}}$. First I don't understand why both $\alpha$ and the arguments have the $-$ sign. Second how is it possible to turn this expression $\sqrt{-(\cos({-\frac{\pi}{4}}) + i\sin{({-\frac{\pi}{4}}}))}$ into this expression $ \cos({-\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{\pi}{2}) + i\sin{({-\frac{\pi}{8}+ \frac{\pi}{2}})}} $.

My opinion: The answer for the first question: the authors of my book didn't solve the problem correctly. The answer for the second question: it's not possible to get rid of a square root when we have a sum of numbers... again a mistake; the arguments of the complex number should look like: $\cos({-\frac{\pi}{8}) + i\sin{({-\frac{\pi}{8}})}}$.

Comment: Did you actually try to solve this yourself? If so what did you get?

Comment: @user160738 The complex equation has two solutions. First for $a \ge 0$ we have $ z_0 = \pm \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2}}(\cos({-\frac{\pi}{8}}) + i\sin{({-\frac{\pi}{8}}))} $ and $z_1 = \pm \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2}}(\cos({-\frac{15\pi}{8}}) + i\sin{({-\frac{15\pi}{8}}))}$;we get the modulus and argument from the fact that $z^2=\varepsilon^{2}(\cos{2\theta} + i \sin{2\theta}) \rightarrow 2\theta = \frac{\pi}{4} + 2k\pi, k\in \mathbb{Z}$ second for $ \alpha \le 0 $... here only the modulus changes with $ \varepsilon = \pm \sqrt{-\frac{\alpha}{2}} $

Comment: @user160738 though the opinion that I've stated in the description of the question can be considered a form of an answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $\alpha\ge 0$. Change your equation into modulus-argument form

$$
2e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}z^2=\sqrt{2}\alpha e^{\frac{\pi}{4}i}
$$

so we have

$$
z^2=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\alpha e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}i}
$$

So in this case solutions are $$\pm \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\alpha} e^{-\frac{\pi}{8}i}$$

Since $\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\alpha}=\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}}}$ your given solution is off by a sqare root sign for $2$

Using relation $-e^{-\frac{\pi}{8}i}=e^{\frac{7\pi}{8}i}$ then solutions in standard modulus-argument form is

$$
 \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\alpha} e^{-\frac{\pi}{8}i} \;\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\;  \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\alpha} e^{\frac{7\pi}{8}i}
$$

Note: $-e^{-\frac{\pi}{8}i}=e^{\frac{7\pi}{8}i}$ is easy to see if you realize that putting $-$ sign just reflects the point in the origin - "$-$ of something" and "something" must be symmetric about origin. Or you can just see that $-e^{-\frac{\pi}{8}i}=-i\sin(-\pi/8)-\cos(-\pi/8)=\cos(\pi-\pi/8)+i\sin(\pi/8)=\cos(7\pi/8)+i\sin(7\pi/8)$. I just used identity $-\cos(x)=\cos(\pi-x)$ and $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$

---

If $\alpha<0$ then just replace $\alpha$ in modulus-argument form by $-\beta$ where $\beta>0$ so $z^2=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\beta e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}i}e^{-\pi i}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\beta e^{-\frac{5\pi}{4}i}$ which is in modulus-argument form, and proceed as before

Comment: Very detailed answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the absolute value of both sides of your equation, you will get $2\lvert z\rvert^2=\lvert\alpha\rvert\sqrt 2$. The absolute value of $z$ is: $\lvert z\rvert=\frac{\sqrt{\lvert\alpha\rvert}}{\sqrt[4]{2}}$, so none of your solutions can be correct.

Comment: if you write the denominator $2=\sqrt[4]{2^4}$ and simplify you'll see that you get the same thing. Also you need to fix your latex so I can read the second formula.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but $|z|$ shouldn't be equal to $\frac {\sqrt{\alpha} \sqrt[4]{2^3}} {2} $. My computations give me: $ |z| = \pm \sqrt{\frac{|\alpha|\sqrt{2}}{2}} = \pm \frac{\sqrt{\alpha}\sqrt[4]{2}}{\sqrt{2}}= \pm \frac{\sqrt{\alpha}2^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}}} {2} = \pm \frac {\sqrt{\alpha}\sqrt[4]{2^3}} {2}$. Sorry I've deleted and reposted the comment because 5 min have passed.

Comment: I recommend you to write the latex in the "answer" box so you can see the result as you type, before copy-paste it in the "comments". At least this is what i do.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm still pretty new here... I didn't think of this trick yet.

Comment: Btw you're right.

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt[4]{2^3}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt[4]{2^3}}{\sqrt[4]{2^4}}=\sqrt[4]\frac{2^3}{2^4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}$. And moreover, the absolute value cannot be negative.